# Microsoft Graph API CalendarView vs Microsoft EWS CalendarView

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

In EWS I can query a calendar with DateTime.Now and  to only get the currently active events.

```
DateTime filterStartDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime filterEndDate = filterStartDate.Date.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);
CalendarView ccView = new CalendarView(filterStartDate, filterEndDate);
```

But it does not seem to work with MS Graphi API, where if the event started before my start filter, it won't show up

```
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
    {
        new QueryOption("startDateTime", filterStartDate.ToString("s")),
        new QueryOption("endDateTime",  filterEndDate .ToString("s"))
     };

 var res = await _graphClient.Users[roomSMTP].CalendarView
      .Request(queryOptions)
      .Header("Prefer", $"outlook.timezone=\"{_outlookTimeZone}\"")
      .Select("start,end,subject,organizer,id").GetAsync();
```

Is this by design or am I missing some sort of filter?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

*The values of `startDateTime` and `endDateTime` are interpreted using the timezone offset specified in the value and are not impacted by the value of the `Prefer: outlook.timezone` header if present. If no timezone offset is included in the value, it is interpreted as UTC.*

I don't know if you are trying out edge cases but maybe you should use `.ToString("o")` (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)).

---

And do you know that your code returns `IUserCalendarViewCollectionRequest` and that you need to iterate over the `calendarViewPages` and get the results for every page?

Comment: It's not the timezone offset I am worried about. It's the fact the EWS returned meetings that were active even if the startDate was less than my filter date

Example: Meeting1 Start 2022-08-25 18:00 -> End 2022-08-25 19:00

If I queried EWS at 18:15 (18:15 to 23:59) it would return the meeting. Graph API returns nothing.

Comment: But the time zone could cause this issue, especially in edge cases. Try to add a bigger range of startDateTime and endDateTime to be safe that this is not the problem.

Comment: I edited my answer. You also need to iterate over the calendarViewPage and request the results of every page.

Comment: You are correct, I didn't not test my edge case before responding.

Comment: Did this cause the problem or are you testing it?

Comment: Formatting the time as .ToString("o") instead of .ToString("s") has solved my problem. Thank you for the tip :)